# If $\sin (B) = − \frac 1 2 $ with $B$ in third quadrant, then find $\cot (B/2)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

If $\sin (B) = − \frac 1 2 $ with $B$ in  third quadrant, then find $\cot (B/2)$

I'm getting $-\sqrt{3}-2$

Comment: I think I made a calculation error. The correct answer should be sqrt(3)-2

Comment: [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot%28arcsin%28-1%2F2%29%2F2%29) says you are right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos B = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so $\cos(\frac{B}{2})$ = $-\sqrt{\dfrac{1 + \cos B}{2}} = -\dfrac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}{2}$, and $\sin(\frac{B}{2}) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - \cos B}{2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}{2}$, from here you can find $\cot(\frac{B}{2})$. From this we see that: $\cot(\frac{B}{2}) = ...= \sqrt{3} - 2$

Comment: It is somewhat more efficient to observe that (i) $2\sin(B/2)\cos(B/2)=-1/2$ and $2\cos^2(B/2)-1=-\sqrt{3}/2$. Thus (ii) $2\cos^2(B/2)=1-\sqrt{3}/2$, and we divide (ii) by (i).

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yeah, that is way better than the one I used. I was just making sure I first got the right answer, then I refine it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) ,

$$\sin B=\frac{2\tan\dfrac B2}{1+\tan^2\dfrac B2}$$

$$\implies\frac{2\tan\dfrac B2}{1+\tan^2\dfrac B2}=-\frac12$$

Rearrange and solve the Quadratic Equation

Now as $\displaystyle180^\circ<B<270^\circ,90^\circ<\frac B2<135^\circ\implies \tan\dfrac B2<0$

Comment: @user125736, How about this?